# How to add client-side validation if I use CommandName for the button?

Tags: asp.net, client-side-validation, onclientclick

I have a code where I have a `asp:Button` control with `CommandName` attribute.  GridView has `OnRowCommand`. When I click the button, I execute a method on `RowCommand` event to update records. Inside of this method I validate input. How can I add client-side validation to that button click event event, so I have validation in both places?

Any suggestons?

Comment: `asp-classic` ? did you mean ASP.NET

Comment: `asp.net`. Thank you for a quick response. I found the way: `onClientClick="if (ValidateEmail(this) == false) return(false);"`. However, somehow inside of ValidateEmail(btn_id) method, my `btn_id` is undefined. But when I remove `this` from a method call, `btn_id` is defined

Comment: Can you show your asp markup

Comment: Thank's I got it. I forgot to append an `id` attribute to `btn_id` inside of my validation method. Happens... :)